# RSpec: Most accurate type for a service test

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

What is the most accurate test type for testing a normal ruby class (PORO) with *rspec* – in my case a service. Normally I would have used a `:model` test.

But just for the sake of idiomatic testing: Is there a way of having an *rspec* test which is thinner than the `:model` type?

Comment: [Non-rails related specs do not require `:type` metadata by default](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/directory-structure#non-rails-related-specs-do-not-require-%60%3Atype%60-metadata-by-default)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [no type to apply](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/directory-structure#non-rails-related-specs-do-not-require-%60%3Atype%60-metadata-by-default). Just treat it as a PORO and write a spec for it. If you really wanted to add a type, you could add `type: :service` but it won't do anything by default.

```
RSpec.describe MyServiceObject do
  # specs
end
```